# is a graphics card active when no monitors are plugged in

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, gpu, dvi

I never had a dedicated graphics card, so far I have only been using Intel HD graphics, the Gigabyte motherboard has Hdmi, Vga and DVI, currently I have 3 monitors plugged into those, I have a spare one lying around and have been planning on getting a graphics card for a while now, so here is my question:

The graphics card I'm getting has an HDMI a DVI and a display port, I can only insert HDMI and DVI in there, now I want to know if the graphics card still does the same job if I plug 2 monitors into the graphics card and 2 into the motherboard, I know you can change the BIOS to allow this, but I want my games to run as smooth as possible, so if I change it to use both graphic drivers, will the GPU still do everything its supposed to do even if there are only half the total monitors plugged into it?

I also don't want to downgrade to only two monitors, so please give me a detailed answer on how it works when two drivers are in use, will the games only run smooth on the monitors that are connected to the graphics card, and can I still extend displays to drag one window overall 4 displays

might be a stupid question but I never had a dedicated graphics card and don't want to make any mistakes when buying one

Comment: Being able to run monitors from both controllers is not guaranteed. You will want to do further research to ensure the mainboard supports this.

Comment: IF you can make both graphics "cards" work together, then the performance will be exactly what each card would be individually. The operating system doesn't care where those monitors are plugged in, and will treat them the same as you are used to. Like @music2myear suggested, being able to run both onboard and add-on video at the same time, is far from a given. Actually, most name brand systems will probably NOT let you do this.

Comment: Typically the onboard Intel HD graphics will be disabled completely (turned off) from bios when a dedicated card is placed into the system. I was not even aware both could be enabled together (as a long time pc gamer) and to do so sounds very messy at the least. I would advise to search for dedicated card supporting 3 outputs and thourougly research if that dedicated card is infact capable of 3 simultanious outputs as opposed to simply having 3 different outputs.

Comment: so if i don't connect any at all to the graphics card, will i still be able to run my 3 monitors from Intel graphics while having the full performance of the graphics card? also, what you're saying is either connect everything to the graphics card or nothing at all? I did a youtube search regarding this motherboard, and it says that when installing a new graphics card it will disable intel's drivers, but you can re-enable them in bios

Comment: This is my pc stats for those wondering https://pastebin.com/ZLiepicD and the video https://youtu.be/Loa-ERZfmZU I checked bios, it has the same options, basicly, if this mannages to work, will i still have the full gpu power even when the games i play are running of other screens connected to the motherboard, or when im rendering, i cant really understand how the gpu works in terms of where its connected. does it only work on the connected screens ? if you could explain that aswell please.

Comment: Notice in the video when he enables TV the computer monitor is now blank. Im not saying cant be done but its typically one or the other. No a dedicated videocard does not re-direct its output to the motherboard output. You can not use any of the dedicated card power from the motherboard output or even get picture. You said you are yet to get the card so get one that supports 3 simultanious outputs. If somebody is giving you a specific card with two outputs then you have a maximium of two screens. Literally every person who games seriously on PC with dedicated just permenantly turns off intelHD